# What can cause a change in the mangled name of a non-virtual thunk to XXX

Tags: c++, abi, name-mangling

I built a middleware library (wxWidgets) with a set of patches that fix issues and add a few features (for Audacity).

Running a previously built copy of a client application (Audacity) against the patched binaries, I get a missing symbol error concerning a `non-virtual thunk to wxTextCtrl::Cut()`. The app rebuilt against the patched libraries runs fine, but gives me the same error when I try to run it against the unpatched library.

Turns out that this non-virtual thunk exists in both libraries, but under a different mangled name (`_ZThn1344_N10wxTextCtrl3CutEv` vs. `_ZThn1352_N10wxTextCtrl3CutEv`).

As far as I can tell the patches do not touch `wxTextCtrl` at all.

What can be the cause for this difference?

Comment: The number after ZThn represents the offset of the virtual base, and will change along with the size of the object. Something must have changed in some class that inherits from wxTextCtrl virtually.

Comment: Ah (but would virtual inheritance affect the virtual thunk, not the non-virtual?). More importantly, why would a parent class be affected by changes in a derivative class? After all you can derive a class in a dependent library, and that's certainly not going to modify symbols in the dependency. Shouldn't I be looking instead for changes to a parent of wxTextCtrl?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the cause was the activation of the accessibility functionality in wxWidgets. I haven't hunted down exactly what changed; the feature adds methods to a good number of classes.